# Need to remove hyphen from the category search box in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

In my prestashop 1.7 application, i need to remove hyphen from the category listing. In that place need to put two spaces.

[image]

```
 $prefix .= '--';

{$node.prefix} {$node.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

i tried   But not working.

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` for adding blank spaces. HTML  DOM parser(in the browser) strips blank spaces otherwise.

Comment: That i not working.

Comment: `$prefix .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';`